# Как растянуть картинку на весь размер экрана

Tags: html, css

Ничего на эту тему не нашел.
Мне нужно что бы картинка не просто увеличивалась, теряя свою часть за границей экрана, а именно **расстягивалась** на всю ширину и высоту, игнорируя пропорции. Пытался `background:url(am.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`, не работает так как мне надо

Comment: на всю высоту и ширину это значит терять пропорции в большинстве случаев. вам там на выбор `background-size: cover/contain`

Comment: Такой вариант не получается, картинка все равно сохраняет пропорции

Comment: сеачало надо указать размер html,body то есть height: 100% потом писать уже background url и background size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div{
    background: url('https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/december-holidays-days-2-30-6753651837108830.5-s.png') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Конечно да, это верно, но как мне определить размер экрана?

Comment: Исправил, элемент растягивается на весь экран, а вместе с ним картинка